# ASP.NET 4.5 does not properly interpret Resource files in nested folder environment

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-4.5

The Web Application has the following hierarchy
Folder Level 1
->Folder Level 2
-->Folder Level 3
Inside Folder Level 3 it has a UserControl that reads a resource key from resource file under the folder *App_LocalResources* using the Method *GetLocalResourceObject*.
The UserControl is being used on a  web page that resides on Folder Level 2. With This structure it is working fine on ASP.Net framework 3.5 but it gives the following error on ASP.Net Framework 4.5.
 *Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "UserControl.ascx.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "App_LocalResources.FolderLevel2.b7661b20.lt_wmckt" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.*
Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: This has nothing to do with nested hierarchy. I figured it out that the Framework 4.5 is quite strict in Naming conventions. The resource file for UserControl.ascx located in App_LocalResources must have the name UserControl.ascx.resx in order to be accessed via GetLocalResourceObject.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with nested hierarchy. I figured it out that the Framework 4.5 is quite strict in Naming conventions for resource files. The resource file for *UserControl.ascx* located in *App_LocalResources* must have the name *UserControl.ascx.resx* in order to be accessed via *GetLocalResourceObject*.